# Javascript, ou outra forma, de apagar certa linha do codigo html, e criar outra no mesmo local da anterior

Tags: javascript, funções

Preciso saber se existe alguma função que selecione uma linha específica do código **HTML** para apagar ela, quando disparar à função, e algo para criar uma nova linha de código no mesmo lugar dá linha apagada, meio que para substituir mesmo.

**OBS:** Literalmente é só uma linha de code :)

Comment: O que você quer dizer com linha? Poderia colocar um exemplo ?

Comment: Você quer apagar um texto/conteúdo ou quer apagar um elemento HTML?

Answer (score 1):

O HTML é constituído por elementos do **[DOM](https://tableless.com.br/tenha-o-dom/)** (*Document Object Model*) e não por linhas. É representado por uma *árvore* de nós, onde um nó pode ser selecionado e modificado via script (ex., JavaScript). Cada nó possui uma posição hierárquica dentro da árvore. O que você precisa fazer é saber qual a posição do elemento que você quer manipular.

Por exemplo, se houver vários elementos `<p>` (parágrafo) no HTML, cada um possui um índice (*index*) na árvore (também possui um *elemento-pai*, pode ter *elementos-irmãos* e até *elementos-filhos*).

> Todos os elementos da página possuem um avô e um pai: `<html>` e `<body>`,
>   respectivamente.

Caso o elemento que você quer modificar possua um `id`, fica bem mais fácil selecioná-lo, porque um `id` é único na página e você pode *ir* direto a ele sem se preocupar com a posição dele na árvore.

O exemplo abaixo mostra a substituição de um parágrafo `<p>` por um link `<a>`:

```js
function funcao(){
   
   // apagar e substituir o primeiro parágrafo <p>
   // por um link <a>
   var el = document.querySelectorAll("p")[0]; // seleciono o primeiro <p>
   var a = document.createElement("a"); // crio o elemento <a>
   var t = document.createTextNode("Novo link"); // crio o texto do <a>
   a.appendChild(t) // adiciono o texto no <a>
   a.setAttribute("href","pagina.html"); // adiciono href no <a>
   el.parentNode.insertBefore(a, el.nextSibling); // insiro o novo elemento <a> após o <p>
   el.outerHTML = ''; // apago o <p>
   
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet odio at interdum euismod. Praesent suscipit tortor ex, vel vestibulum eros rhoncus eu. Phasellus efficitur dui ut tincidunt eleifend.</p>
<p>Nullam finibus facilisis risus, nec vehicula tortor efficitur a. Suspendisse at nibh elementum elit volutpat fermentum vel a eros. Vestibulum at condimentum nisi.</p>
<input type="button" onclick="funcao()" value="Clique aqui para substituir">
```